# Can't upload files to my website [PHP]

Tags: php, html

I'm really new to PHP and I followed a tutorial for this but I'm unable to make this work. When I upload an image it gives me the failed message, but why I don't really see any problems I tried writting the code 2 times but still have the same problem.

The idea of this code is to be able to upload an image and once uploaded would actually be the users profile picture (there is some more code in on other file for that function), but it isn't working because the image isn't uploaded, you can try to upload any kind of image but it will just display the upload=failed message and that is supposed to happen if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination)) isn't right but why wouldn't it be right ? I really don't understand guys it's been 2 days my project is blocke because of this. I searched and some people talked about permissions but I don't really know what they mean by that and how do I even permit the file to be uploaded or edited.

So my real problem is I can't get the files that wants to be uploaded get moved to "uploads" file, it displays the upload=failed and not the upload=success because it is unable to move the upload file to the "uploads" folder.

this is where it starts to give issues:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination)) {
    $sql = "UPDATE profileimg SET status=0 WHERE userid='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    header("Location: ../index.php?upload=success");
}
else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?upload=failed");
}
```

Thanks for any ideas!

here is the full code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbh-inc.php';
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['avatar'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['avatar']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['avatar']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['avatar']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'ico');

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
        if ($fileError === 0) {
            if ($fileSize < 500000) {
                $fileNameNew = "profile".$id.".".$fileActualExt;

                $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination)) {
                    $sql = "UPDATE profileimg SET status=0 WHERE userid='$id'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    header("Location: ../index.php?upload=success");
                }
                else {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?upload=failed");
                }
            }
            else {
                header("Location: ../index.php?upload=toobigfile");
            }
        }
        else {
            header("Location: ../index.php?upload=error");
        }
    }
    else {
        header("Location: ../index.php?upload=invalidtype");
    }
}
```

Comment: "it isn't working" is too broad! Explain what's going on, if there are errors, or if nothing is happening. Also shorten your example code, put only relevant parts, this help YOU to find the problem, since you will need to isolate only the pieces of the code that doesn't work as expected. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want to be helped here.

Comment: start wti some debugging`if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination)){    echo  "file moved successfully"; exit();
}
else{
    echo " STILL DID NOT MOVE"; print_r ($_FILES);exit();
}`

Comment: Ok thanks for the advices i'll remove some code that isn't really usefull and put more info in my post, I hope that it will be good now. And i'll try your idea rtfm thanks.

Comment: lot of echoing will help you in this case also check if the folder has permissions to be written to

Comment: Jack I told it in my post I don't know what permissions you guys are talking about ^^ pls explain.

Comment: So I think I found the permissions you guys are talking about, I right clicked my uploads folder in my ftp and I checked everything inside (the 3 permissions) but it still doesn't work so If that is what you guys are talking about it doesn't work

Comment: You still haven't told us what the error or exception or actual problem is. "It's not working" is not enough for us to debug the issue.

Comment: Wow guys I just found the problem ... I don't know why this was the problem but in the $fileDestination = 'uploads'.$fileNameNew; I had to put $fileDestination = '../uploads'.$fileNameNew;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow guys I just found the problem ... I don't know why this was the problem but in the $fileDestination = 'uploads'.$fileNameNew; I had to put $fileDestination = '../uploads'.$fileNameNew;

```
if ($fileSize < 500000) {
            $fileNameNew = "profile".$id.".".$fileActualExt;

            $fileDestination = '../uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
            if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination)) {
                $sql = "UPDATE profileimg SET status=0 WHERE userid='$id'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                header("Location: ../index.php?upload=success");
            }
            else {
                header("Location: ../index.php?upload=failed");
            }
        }
```